# Thread for Background Music

Tags: c

I have a homework assignment. I am supposed to make a calculator and add background music. I use Dev-C++ and C on windows.
 I need a thread when I want to use music and calculator. I am going to use `process.h` for thread. I tried using `_beginthread` but it raised an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>

void asd()
{
    printf("hello");
}

int main()
{
    _beginthread(asd(),333,(void*)NULL);    _endthread();
}
```

and error is

```
[invalid use of void expression]
```

How can I do this assignment?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `asd` instead of passing its address. Since the function has a `void` return, you are incorrectly passing `void` where a function pointer is expected. Remove the parentheses.

```
int main()
{
    _beginthread(asd, 333, (void*)NULL);
}
```

And the function `asd` must accept a void pointer parameter as well.

```
void asd(void*)
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

Comment: @Mrprintf: Yes. Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: I can understand your sentence but what should i do. Can you explain it? My english is not very good so please explain simple.

Comment: The `asd` function you have defined takes no parameters. The thread required a pointer to a function that accepts a `void*` parameter. So it doesn't match, and the compiler is telling you so. I've added a modified `asd` to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I search thread on windows about 1 week and solved problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Now I want to play 2 music same time I read same function in main but only 1 is played. How can do it?